# Compare two long project list with various resources per project

Tags: excel

I am trying to compare a list of resources on various projects in one week to a list of resources on various projects in another week.  The goal being to list for those projects where resources increased, What were they working on last week (What did we stop doing).

Resources work on multiple projects in a given week and there are 100s of projects.  Typical vlookups, pivots, etc are not yielding results.  Any ideas?

Sample:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Not completely clear (at least to me), maybe you can share a small data sample?

Comment: Not sure how to post a picture of sample data here.  Imagine a long list of projects.  The available projects themselves is static.  The amount of work that a given resource can work on each can vary.  I am trying to show what a given resource is working on this week and working on last week, to show what is not being done (capacity is fixed, if a new project is taken on, something is decreased from the week prior).

Comment: I have tried traditional pivot tables and vlookups based on names - but with a series of data where a name can map to various projects - i only get the first entry

Comment: For example you could edit your post, use `code formatting` to list the headers of the sheet: `Project | Resources |  % use | Week ` and list some rows of data: `Project1 | Resource3 | 30% | 21`. I invented, but without any info about data I (anybody I guess) can not try to help.

Comment: okay, I edited main post

Comment: You also have a few project typos

Comment: I don't see what you want for a result.  To make your question more useful, so I can better help you, try taking a look at [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And to provide an example that can be easily copied/pasted into a worksheet (which a screenshot cannot), try the [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)